# Prestashop 1.7 shipping not calculated

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

Good evening all,

I have a problem with presta 1.7.5, the shipping costs are not displayed correctly,
this is both logged in and not.

Also the shipping costs are not fully calculated, see attachments.

I can only find it on the forum about deleting the display of free shipping, but that's not the problem.

I have configured everything (carriers, countries etc) It is also available as a carrier.
Anyone have an idea?

I have been familiar with prestashop and the systems for years, but here I just do not get out.

[Shoppingcart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfzfP.jpg)

[carrier select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMf7H.jpg)

[overview order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9Vws.jpg) (Total is not calculated right, and bottom, and also not for payment)

Answer (score 0):

I don't got an answer to your question, but you might want to change your overview order picture, all your details are in there ;-)